# Lifting isogeny over étale cover

Tags: etale-covers, isogenies, kummer-theory

I am in the situation where I need to lift a particular isogeny over an étale cover, and I am not sure how to justify the existence of such a lift. I am trying to fill in the details of the proof of Proposition 2.1.4 in Mars-Springer's *Character sheaves*, which computes the Kummer local systems on a torus.

Let $k = \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ and let $T = k^\times$ be an algebraic torus of rank 1. I have a Galois étale covering $p : Y \to T$ which is cyclic of degree dividing $m$, for some $m$ coprime to $p$. Because the corresponding extension of function fields $k(Y) / k(T)$ is also cyclic of degree dividing $m$, Kummer theory says that I can find some $x \in k(T)$ such that $k(Y) = k(T)(x^{\frac{1}{m}})$. Because $p$ is unramified, $x$ can have neither poles nor zeroes. Because it has no poles, it is actually regular, so $x \in k[T] = k[y,y^{-1}]$. Writing $x$ has a sum of monomials, we note that if $x$ has more than one monomial summand, we can factor out a polynomial which then has a nonzero root, contradicting the fact that $x$ has no roots in $T$. Thus $x$ is actually a monomial, i.e. a character of $T$.

The authors seem to think it immediately follows that the $m^{th}$ power isogeny
\begin{align*}
m : T &\to T \\
t &\mapsto t^m
\end{align*}
lifts over $p$, which they phrase as "the $m$-isogeny of $T$ factors: $T \to X \xrightarrow{p} T$". It is not clear to me why this follows immediately from the fact that $x$ is a character, or even how the two statements are related.

I have been trying to show that $m$ satisfies the lifting criterion, i.e. that
$$ m_*(\pi_1(Y, \tilde e)) \subseteq p_*(\pi_1(T, e)). $$
My idea was that, because $x = y^i$ is a monomial, it commutes with $m$. If I could relate $x$ and $m$ to the cover $p$ somehow, maybe with something like $p = x^{\frac{1}{m}} \circ m$ (I don't claim this expression is correct, I just want to give an example of what I am trying to do) then perhaps commutativity would allow me to relate the induced maps on the étale fundamental groups.

I have not really been able to make headway with this approach. Mars-Springer doesn't mention the lifting criterion or étale fundamental group at all, so perhaps I am massively overcomplicating this. Does anyone see how to fill in this step (or know of a resource that possibly gives more details)?

P.S. The authors really seem to emphasize that $m$ is an isogeny, but don't (explicitly) use it anywhere. I have never studied isogenies in any particular detail, so perhaps there is some general result about isogenies that would allow us to conclude immediately. If so, a reference for such a result would be much appreciated.